# If $x = a^3 \pmod{p}$ and $x = a^2 \pmod{p}$, is it true that $x = a \pmod{p}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm a little confused about how to start this, or if it's even true. Any pointers are appreciated, thank you. $p$ represents a prime number.

Comment: A good way to start is to try out an easy example. You also should explain the notation. Does $p$ denote a prime number?

Comment: yes it does! Thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

If prime $p$ divides $a^3-a^2=a^2(a-1)$, then $p$ divides $a^2$ or $a-1$, so what is $a\bmod p$?

Comment: I've come across this question, and I'm trying to use your hint. So we know that $p$ divides $a^2$ or $a-1$, which means that $a^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ or $a \equiv 1 \pmod p$. But I can't continue from here. Any other hints?

Comment: That means $a\equiv0\pmod p$ or $a\equiv1\pmod p$, which means $a^2\equiv0\pmod p$ or $a^2\equiv1\pmod p$, respectively; so now you should know what $x$ is $\pmod p$, so you can determine if it is true that $x\equiv a\pmod p$

Comment: How is $a \equiv 0 \pmod p$? I know that if $a \equiv b \pmod N \implies a^k \equiv b^k \pmod N$, not the other way around...

Comment: If **prime** $p$ divides $a^2$, then $p$ divides $a$

Answer (score 2):

We can rewrite these congruences as equations in the finite field $\Bbb F_p$ as
$$
x=a^3=a^2.
$$
Either $a=0$ or by cancelling $a^2$ in $a^3=a^2$ we obtain $a=1$, so that $x=a$ in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is a prime it is true since $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is a field, mod $8$ it is not true, take $4$. $0=4^2$ mod $8$, $0=4^3$ mod $8$

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an accepted answer yet, so I will use the hint that J. W. Tanner gave to provide you with the full solution.

$$ \left. \begin{aligned} x &\equiv a^3 \pmod p \\ x&\equiv a^2 \pmod p \end{aligned}  \right\} \implies a^3 - a^2 = a^2(a - 1) \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

Therefore, $p$ divides either $a^2$ or $a - 1$ (by [Euclid's first theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclidsTheorems.html)).

**Case $1$:**
If $p$ divides $a^2$, then $a^2 \equiv  0 \pmod p$, and so $a \equiv 0 \pmod p$ (This works only because $p$ is prime. If $p$ is not prime, then $a^k \equiv b^k \nrightarrow a \equiv b \pmod p$ for nonnegative $k$).

Since we have that $x \equiv a^2 \pmod p$, and $a^2 \equiv a \equiv 0 \pmod p$, then $x \equiv a \equiv 0 \pmod p$

**Case $2$:**
If $p$ divides $a-1$, then $a-1 \equiv  0 \pmod p$, and so $a \equiv 1 \pmod p$. This means that $a^2 \equiv  1 \pmod p$.

Since we have that $x \equiv a^2 \pmod p$, and $a^2 \equiv a \equiv 1 \pmod p$, then $x \equiv a \equiv 1 \pmod p$.